# ASP.NET MVC 5 + EF6 + Ninject - Multitenancy Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ninject

I have a business ASP.NET MVC5 application where each customer has his own database. I want to use EF6 and Ninject for DI. For login I'm using ASP.NET Identity.

For each user exists a UserClaim where the name of the database is specified:

1. UserId = 1 | ClaimType = "db_name" | ClaimValue = "Customer0001"
2. UserId = 2 | ClaimType = "db_name" | ClaimValue = "Customer0002"

and so on... This means it is one web-application with a "shared" database for user authentication and on the other side each customers has his own database - all databases are located on the same database server (MS SQL Server).

The user need to login in, after login he should receive data from his personal database (specified in the UserClaim-Table).

For Ninject I think I have to something like this

```
private void AddBindings() {
   kernel.Bind<EFDBContext>().ToMethod(c => new EFDBContext("db_name"));
}
```

But how would I get the UserClaim into the bindings? (I don't want to use a Session, because sessions can get lost).

And what steps after the bindings are necessary?

For example at the AccountRepository the EFDBContext expects the "db_name" > but how would I get it there?

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository {
    private EFDBContext context = new EFDBContext("db_name");
}
```

And finally I can change the connection string inside of this class??

```
public class EFDBContext : DbContext {
    public EFDBContext(string db_name) : base("EFDBContext") {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE AFTER @Hooman Bahreini ANSWER**

NinjectDependencieResolver.cs

```
private void AddBindings() {
    kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("http_current_context", HttpContext.Current);
}
```

CustomerRepository.cs

```
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository {

        private CustomerDBContext context;

        public CustomerRepository(HttpContext httpContext) {

            string db_name = "";
            var claimValue = ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "db_name");

            if(claimValue != null) {
                db_name = claimValue.Value.ToString();
            }

            context = new CustomerDBContext(db_name);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Test> Tests {
            get { return context.Test; }
        }
    }
```

DB-Context-File

```
    public class CustomerDBContext : DbContext {

        public CustomerDBContext(string db_name) : base("CustomerDBContext") {

            string temp_connection = Database.Connection.ConnectionString.Replace(";Initial Catalog=;", ";Initial Catalog=" + db_name + ";");

            Database.Connection.ConnectionString = temp_connection;
        }

        public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access user claims from `HttpContext`:

```
var claimValue = ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User)
                 .Claims
                 .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "db_name");
```

For your ninject code, you can create an extension method for `HttpContext`:

```
public static HttpcontextExtensions 
{
    public static string GetDbName(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return ((ClaimsPrincipal)context.Current.User)
               .Claims
               .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "db_name");
    }
}
```

And use the following ninject binding:

```
kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>()
    .To<CustomerRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("db_name", HttpContext.GetDbName());
```

See [this document](https://sung.codes/blog/2016/12/04/pass-httpcontext-ninject-asp-net-mvc/) for more info about accessing `HttpContext` in ninject.

---

In your example, `CustomerRepository` has a dependency on `HttpContext`, this is not a good design. `CustomerRepository` requires a db-name, and that's what should be passed in the constructor. Related to this is [Nikola’s 4th law of IoC](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/)

> Every constructor of a class being resolved should not have any
>   implementation other than accepting a set of its own dependencies.

To give you an example, you don't have any `HttpContext` in your test project, which makes unit testing `CustomerRepository` complicated.

P.S. I don't know your design, but maybe getting db-name from `HttpContext` is not an ideal solution... user may logout or clear their browser history and you will loose your db-name.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The link helped me to solve this. Basically it is working as expected => User gets data from his own customer database. I have done it in a custom way and not exactly as in your posted link. I'm not completely sure if I have done it the rigth way. I have updated my original post => could you please review and check if my solution is okay? (It is working basically but I'm not sure if it is a recommended approach).

Comment: Hmmm. I have done some mistake in my code. I have used `HttpContext.Current.User` directly in the repository. The ninject binding with WithConstructorArgument has no effect. But I'm not fully understanding this. If I can access the `HttpContext.Current.User` directly in my ninject-domain, why do I need the solution from you link? I can use the HttpContext directly in the `public class CustomerDBContext : DbContext`

Comment: The solution in the link was just for your reference, I have updated the answer... you need to pass db-name to your repository (not `HttpContext`)

Comment: Thank you, for explanation - especially for the dependency on HttpContext. Related to your PS: what would be a better solution? I just get the db-name of the customer after he logged in (from a shared user-db). So I can just get the user-db-name from UserClaims. If the user logout I don't need the db-name anymore, because there isn't anything to do in the customer-db if he isn't authenticated. (What do you mean with clear browser history? => I suppose you mean clearing the cookies, clearing the history itselfs shouldn't affect anything?)

Comment: @Phoniex: if the answer has been helpful you can indicate that by voting/accepting the answer. Regarding the P.S. I don't know your design, it was just a point of caution. Correct, I meant clearing the cookies.